# Python: changing list values based on previous value

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to convert signal values in a list that return either 1, 0 or -1 depending on the previous values, like so:

Example signal list:

```
myList = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1]
```

Output should be:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Meaning that if the first encountered signal is 1 or -1 then it should be saved to the list, while the next values should be equal to 0 until the opposite signal occurs. I managed to achieve it with this function:

```
def print_list(list_to_convert):
    first_list, final_list=[], []
    value = 0
    for x in list_to_convert:
        if x != 0 and x != value:
            value = x
        first_list.append(value)
        
    value = 0
    for x in first_list:
        if x != value:
            value = x
            final_list.append(x)
        else:
            final_list.append(0)
    return final_list
```

But that's not the most elegant way. Could you please provide more pythonic solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just need to trace the non-zero signal 1 and -1, you can just record the previous non-zero signal as a "flag".

```
def print_list(list_to_convert):
    flag = 0 # record the last non-zero signal
    convert_result = []
    for i in list_to_convert:
        if i != 0 and i != flag: # if the signal is non-zero and different with the flag
            convert_result.append(i) # record it to result
            flag = i # don't forget to update the flag
        else:
            convert_result.append(0)
    return convert_result
```